# AWS CLI to find EC2's security groups id and subnet id

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, resources, command-line-interface

Is there a way to use AWS CLI to find EC2's security groups id and subnet id of a particular instance?

I.e., I want to programmatically find this, and its subnet id

[image]

Comment: "EC2's security groups id and subnet id" for what?  for a particular instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances
```

This will return information about *all* instances.

To obtain information about a *specific* instance, you can use:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-xxx
```

To obtain specific parameters, you could use:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,NetworkInterfaces[].Groups[].GroupId,NetworkInterfaces[].SubnetId]'
```

Please note that an Amazon EC2 instance can have multiple Network Interfaces and multiple Security Groups, so the formatting will be a challenge if you wish to capture the output and use it in some way.

Alternatively, you could use an [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/developer/tools/) to programmatically request the information (eg using Java or Python).