# JMESPath to return as json

Tags: json, jmespath

JMESPath can be used to query json but the return is no longer json any more:

E.g., searching `{"a": "foo", "b": "bar", "c": "baz"}` with JMESPath `a` will yield `"foo"`.

How can I return `{"a": "foo"}` instead?

[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/) is able to do it:

`curl 'https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/commits?per_page=5' | jq '.[0] | {message: .commit.message, name: .commit.committer.name}'`

```
{
  "message": "Merge pull request #162 from stedolan/utf8-fixes\n\nUtf8 fixes. Closes #161",
  "name": "Stephen Dolan"
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I made returning `{"a": "foo"}` works but not for more complicates situation, like JMESPath query from [AWS CLI to find EC2's security groups id and subnet id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73781484/aws-cli-to-find-ec2s-security-groups-id-and-subnet-id). I.e.,

- query `'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,NetworkInterfaces[].Groups[].GroupId,NetworkInterfaces[].SubnetId]'` works, but when I tried to adapt it to
- query `'Reservations[].Instances[].{InstanceId: InstanceId, SubnetId: NetworkInterfaces[].Groups[].GroupId,NetworkInterfaces[].SubnetId}'`

It then no longer working. Got error of:

> Bad value for --query Reservations[].Instances[].{InstanceId: InstanceId, SubnetId: NetworkInterfaces[].Groups[].GroupId,NetworkInterfaces[].SubnetId}: Expecting: colon, got: flatten: Parse error at column 116, token "[]" (FLATTEN), for expression:
> "Reservations[].Instances[].{InstanceId: InstanceId, SubnetId: NetworkInterfaces[].Groups[].GroupId,NetworkInterfaces[].SubnetId}"

Is it the limitation of JMESPath or `aws ec2 describe-instances` command?

You can get the sample input from https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/2.0.34/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html, or better, from https://pastebin.com/JaFwn5ZH.

Comment: The error is clear `Expecting: colon, ...`.  A key is missing in the dictionary, e.g. `, key: NetworkInterfaces[].`   Open a new question if you have other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [MultiSelect Hash](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#multiselect-hash). For example,

```py
>>> import jmespath
>>> expression = jmespath.compile('{a: a}')
>>> expression.search({"a": "foo", "b": "bar", "c": "baz"})
{'a': 'foo'}
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, I made the simple returning {"a": "foo"} works but not for more complicates situations. Please see the updated OP and see if you can identify the problem. Thx!!

Comment: Make the case [mre]. Your first question is an excellent example. The second one is exactly the opposite.

Comment: Sorry, didn't expecting that data from aws doc would be full of errors -- I've already corrected two obvious ones, which is why I said _"or better"_. This is the one that should be working: ~~https://pastebin.com/vR3BA3b5~~. This one: https://pastebin.com/DSV6BvhN, verified!